# Implementing GCM Send-to-Sync

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

The Google Cloud Messaging documentation outlines Send-to-Sync as:

*A send-to-sync (collapsible) message is often a "tickle" that tells a mobile application to sync data from the server. For example, suppose you have an email application. **When a user receives new email on the server, the server pings the mobile application with a "New mail" message**. This tells the application to sync to the server to pick up the new email.*

However, there is no clear methodology to implement a server side PHP script that would listen in for new messages in real-time and then send batches of GCM "sync" requests only to the proper `registration_ids` of users with new messages.

How can this feature be implemented in PHP?